# Set select option value selected during edit in Laravel using jQuery (Dependent Dropdown Select2)

Tags: jquery, laravel

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#country-dd').on('change', function() {
            var idCountry = this.value;
            $("#state-dd").html('');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('api/fetch-states')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    country_id: idCountry,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#state-dd').html('<option value="">Select State</option>');
                    $.each(result.states, function(key, value) {
                        $("#state-dd").append('<option value="' + value
                            .id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });


                    $('#city-dd').html('<option value="">Select City</option>');
                }
            });
        });


        $('#country-dd').trigger("change");



        $('#state-dd').on('change', function() {
            var idState = this.value;
            $("#city-dd").html('');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('api/fetch-cities')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    state_id: idState,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#city-dd').html('<option value="">Select City</option>');
                    $.each(res.cities, function(key, value) {
                        $("#city-dd").append('<option value="' + value
                            .id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });



    });
</script>
```

**How can I set Country, State and City Id value from database while updating record.**

These dropdown are dependent.
It is working fine while adding the record to database
but **How can I set Country, State and City Id value from database while updating record.**